# Bash script to grep string from latest files in folder

Tags: grep

Can you help me with a bash script to grep string from latest files in folder. e.g. I have a folder `/var/log/folder` with some files, and I need to every 30 seconds grep text string `some string` from latest 5 files and result should be written in file `/var/log/file.txt`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Stack overflow is really for dealing with specific problems, rather than a "please do this for me" or "please show me a tutorial" sort of site. If you could provide examples of what you have tried already and say why it isn't working, that would be helpful. You may find your question being closed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it
You'd need to put it into cron

```
cd /var/log/folder && grep "some string" `ls -c | head -n 5\` > /var/log/file.txt
```

if you need to append to the log, use `>>` rather than `>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script. Just modify condition in `while` loop as per your requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir="/var/log/"
rm ${mydir}/file.txt
while [ 1 ]
do
        date >>  ${mydir}/file.txt
        ls -tr ${mydir}/folder/ | tail -n 5 | awk -v var="${mydir}" '{print var"/folder/"$1}' | xargs grep "Some String" >> ${mydir}/file.txt
        sleep 30
done
```